# SSLError in Requests module on Android

Tags: android, python, python-requests, kivy, buildozer

I am writing a Kivy app for Android, packaged with buildozer.  The app authenticates with a web service using the requests module.  However, upon attempting to log in, it throws an exception:

```
I/python  ( 1214):    File "/home/kivy/src/.buildozer/android/app/_applibs/requests/se
ssions.py", line 471, in request
I/python  ( 1214):    File "/home/kivy/src/.buildozer/android/app/_applibs/requests/se
ssions.py", line 579, in send
I/python  ( 1214):    File "/home/kivy/src/.buildozer/android/app/_applibs/requests/ad
apters.py", line 430, in send
I/python  ( 1214):  requests.exceptions.SSLError: Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.
I/python  ( 1214): Python for android ended.
```

Note that if I run the app on my Windows machine, it works fine.

SSL appears to be part of the standard library, so I was under the impression that I shouldn't have to add SSL to the requirements in buildozer.spec.  Nevertheless, I tried adding it there, and it failed to build entirely.

Since the requests module is actually listed as an example at http://buildozer.readthedocs.org/en/latest/specifications.html#section-app, I would anticipate that someone must have had it working at some point.

Is there some other setting I need to use in the buildozer.spec, or somewhere else, to get the module working properly?  Or is there just no way to get it working with https?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding openssl to the requirements.

Comment: The error doesn't seem to have changed any after adding openssl to the requirements.  It builds successfully, but requests still throws.

Comment: I tried it again today, and for whatever reason, it worked.

Comment: Thanks, I had to do a clean and rebuild for it to work